# Setting leader line properties of annotation feature classes

Tags: labeling, arcgis-pro, cartography, annotation

How does one go about setting leader line properties with an annotation feature class? When I reduce the size of the font of the annotation, the leader line stays the same size, so  currently I have small text with a big fat leader line. The only [Pro-related answer](https://community.esri.com/thread/214519-can-you-edit-the-appearance-of-leader-lines-in-arcgis-pro) I've found so far is to edit the behavior in the label properties, but I can't do that because I'm not making these from labels; I'm making notes on a map, highlighting specific features or areas of interest.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done very little with annotations in ArcGIS Pro but I believe you create and set your call out in the annotation class **on creation of the symbol** from within the *Catalog Panel*. It appears you are unable to retrospectively change it. I may be wrong on that? You can certainly add new classes.

To understand what I am suggesting watch the video below.

[image: ArcGIS Pro and setting a call out leader video]

Comment: I certainly haven't seen where you can change it after it's done. I think that's definitely an oversight in the design of the edit tools not to include that capability, and to instead have to edit it at the feature-class level. Oh well, this works for me and my purposes. Thank you!